# update column from one table to another mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to copy a column from one table to another table.

One table contains just upc column and I want to copy those upcs to another table that have upc column equals to NULL

```
table A 
upc
1011
2022
3034
4033
5044

table B
id   name    upc
1    stuff   NULL
2    stuff2  NULL
3    stuff3  2344
4    stuff4  3444
```

essentially the end result should be

```
table B
id   name    upc
1    stuff   1011
2    stuff2  2022
3    stuff3  2344
4    stuff4  3444
```

This is what I have tried. However, all columns update to NULL. Definitely not a desired effect.

```
UPDATE t1
RIGHT JOIN
upcs t2
ON      t1.upc = t2.upc
SET     t1.upc = t2.upc
WHERE   t1.upc IS NULL
```

Would appreciate if someone gave me a hand with this one. Thanks

Comment: is there a foreign key in Table B to point to Table A?

Comment: No there is no foreign key in Table B that points to Table A. Table A only has one column

Comment: you should check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no foreign keys to join both tables, and you are looking to join the rows in the exact order they are listed then in the database

give this a try.

```
SET @id=0;

UPDATE table_b AS b
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT @id:=@id+1 AS id, upc
    FROM table_a
) AS a ON a.id = b.id
SET b.upc = a.upc 
WHERE b.upc IS NULL;
```

What this code does is number the row in table B `1, 2, 3, .......n` Then it join table_a to table_b using the row number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tableB 
SET upc = a.upc 
FROM (SELECT upc FROM tableA) a WHERE tableB.id = tableA.id
```